# Shaders are never available for debug

Tags: nvidia, hlsl, shader

I am trying to debug the shaders using the NVIDIA Parallel Nsight 2.1 but I am unable to do so. As soon as I start debug with Nsight there is a message in Shaders window "**Shader Debugger is not available**". So, I googled this problem and found this [link](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=205548). I have tried all the options that are discussed into the above thread, still no success.

If any of you guys have any experience of debugging shaders, then please help me with this problem.

Thanks,

Pankaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running a optimus enabled Nvidia card. They don't support shader debugging on Optimus enabled video cards. Requirements are described [here](http://developer.nvidia.com/parallel-nsight-requirements).

Comment: Thank you all I figured out why I wasn't able to debug the shaders. I was using the optimus graphics card and because of which I wasn't able to debug the shaders.